# Fast find a DWORD position in array of byte delphi

Tags: delphi-2010

finding fastest way to find dword in array of byte

I have this dword for example. I implemented a method but its slow because I convert byte array to hex string and search the dword as string, the conversion takes up most of the time!!

> need to find  pos of this dword --> **01 49 08 EF 48 C0 C6 91**

```
var
 myarray:array of byte;
 p:integer;
begin
 p:= pos('014908EF48C0C691',array2hex(myarray));
end;
```

i need to find the position of the dword fast search in byte array with out converting !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DWORD` is 4 bytes, so `01 49 08 EF 48 C0 C6 91` is too large to be a single `DWORD`.  It is either 2 `DWORD` values, or it is a `(U)Int64`.

But either way, converting the array to a `string` is definitely the wrong way to go. Just search the raw array data as-is instead, eg:

```
const
  bytesToFind: array[0..7] of Byte = ($01, $49, $08, $EF, $48, $C0, $C6, $91);
var
  myarray: array of byte;
  I, FoundAtIndex, Len: integer;
begin
  myarray := ...;
  Len := Length(myarray);
  FoundAtIndex := -1;
  for I := 0 to Len-8 do
  begin
    if (myarray[I] = $01) and
       ((I+8) <= Len) and
       CompareMem(@myarray[I], @bytesToFind, 8) then
    begin
      FoundAtIndex := I;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if FoundAtIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    // use FoundAtIndex as needed...
  end else
  begin
    // not found...
  end;
end;
```